# Update label content on click using Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to update the content of a label, in Python, by clicking a button. For each clicks a counter will be raised and the value of the label will be updated by the current value of the counter (j). Here is the code:

```
import time 
import random
import MySQLdb
from Tkinter import *
j=0

def PrintNumber():
    global j
    j+=1
    print j
    return      

mgui=Tk()
mgui.geometry('200x200')
mgui.title('Queue System')

st = Button(mgui, text="Next Customer", command = PrintNumber)
st.pack()
f = PrintNumber()
label = Label(mgui, text=f)
label.pack()

mgui.mainloop()
```

Please be kind, i'm new in Python. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Tkinter [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instance to hold a value. If you assign the `textvariable` option of the `Label` widget to the variable class instance, it will update automatically as the value of the instance changes. Here's an example:

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()

var = IntVar() # instantiate the IntVar variable class
var.set(0)     # set it to 0 as the initial value

# the button command is a lambda expression that calls the set method on the var,
# with the var value (var.get) increased by 1 as the argument    
Button(root, text="Next Customer", command=lambda: var.set(var.get() + 1)).pack()

# the label's textvariable is set to the variable class instance
Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the label text in the function that responds to the command (`PrintNumber()` in this case) using `label.config()`, e.g.:

```
from tkinter import *

def PrintNumber():
    global j,label
    j+=1
    label.config(text=str(j))
    return     

j = 0

mgui=Tk()
mgui.geometry('200x200')
mgui.title('Queue System')

st = Button(mgui, text="Next Customer", command = PrintNumber)
st.pack()
label = Label(mgui, text=str(j))
label.pack()
mgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: `str()` on `j` is not needed (tkinter take care of it), and the alternate writing of configure is worth noting:  `label.config(text=str(j))` is equivalent to `label["text"] = j`. Pedantically, `global label` is not needed since you do not write the variable.

Comment: @ather0s: Glad we've solved your problem. To show that the problem has been solved and save other people trying to help further, you could tick one of the answers to show that you've accepted it. Personally, I think the solution provided by atlasologist is the most elegant so I'd recommend that you accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could do it

```
import time 
import random
import MySQLdb
from Tkinter import *


def PrintNumber(label):
    PrintNumber.counter += 1 #simulates a static variable
    print PrintNumber.counter
    label.configure(text=str(PrintNumber.counter)) #you update label here

mgui=Tk()
mgui.geometry('200x200')
mgui.title('Queue System')

PrintNumber.counter = 0 #add an attribute to a function and use it as a static variable

label = Label(mgui) #create label

#pass the label as parameter to your function using lambda notation
st = Button(mgui, text="Next Customer", command=lambda label=label:PrintNumber(label))
st.pack()
label.pack()

mgui.mainloop()
```